# How to terminate windows service with blocking call using TcpListener

Tags: windows-services, tcplistener

I have a windows service which runs a separate background thread.  Inside the thread it starts a TCP server which listens to clients using TcpListener.

I'd like to know how I can close the service down gracefully when there is a blocking read like so:

```
listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

I've found that apparently a windows service can abort any other threads as long as they are set-up as background threads, but what if one of the threads is blocking? Does this make a difference and if so, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way will be to call `listener.Close()` on service's stopping event. It will abort blocking call with `SocketException`.

State of the thread (blocked or running) does not affect the fact that thread is background. So if you call `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` from a background thread it will still be aborted when service stops,

Comment: What if I didn't call listener.Close()? Is this bad?

Comment: @jaffa expected behavior wise - still fine. Last two lines of my answer explain that.